# Matlab Data Preprocessing and Dynamic Struct Assignments

Tags: excel, matlab, matrix, vector, struct

I'm quite new to Matlab and I'm struggling trying to figure out how to properly preprocess my data in order to make some calculations with it.

I have an Excel table with financial log returns of many companies such that every row is a day and every column is a company:

[image]

I imported everything correctly into Matlab like this:

[image]

Now I have to create what's caled "rolling windows". To do this I use the following code:

```
function [ROLLING_WINDOWS] = setup_returns(RETURNS)

    bandwidth = 262;
    [rows, columns] = size(RETURNS);

    limit_rows = rows - bandwidth;


    for i = 1:limit_rows
        ROLLING_WINDOWS(i).SYS = RETURNS(i:bandwidth+i-1,1);
    end

end
```

Well if I run this code for the first column of returns everything works fine... but my aim is to produce the same thing for every column of log returns. So basically I have to add a second for loop... but what I don't get is which syntax I need to use in order to make that ".SYS" dynamic and based on my array of string cells containing company names so that...

```
ROLLING_WINDOWS(i)."S&P 500" = RETURNS(i:bandwidth+i-1,1);
ROLLING_WINDOWS(i)."AIG" = RETURNS(i:bandwidth+i-1,2);
and so on...
```

Thanks for your help guys!

EDIT: working function

```
function [ROLLING_WINDOWS] = setup_returns(COMPANIES, RETURNS)

    bandwidth = 262;
    [rows, columns] = size(RETURNS);

    limit_rows = rows - bandwidth;

    for i = 1:limit_rows
        offset = bandwidth + i - 1;
        for j = 1:columns
            ROLLING_WINDOWS(i).(COMPANIES{j}) = RETURNS(i:offset, j);
        end
    end

end
```

Ok everything is perfect... just one question... matlab intellissense tells me "ROLLING_WINDOWS appears to change size on every loop iteration bla bla bla consider preallocating"... how can I perform this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.  Use dynamic field names by building strings for fields.  Your fields are in a cell array called `COMPANIES` and so:

```
function [ROLLING_WINDOWS] = setup_returns(COMPANIES, RETURNS)

    bandwidth = 262;
    [rows, columns] = size(RETURNS);

    limit_rows = rows - bandwidth;

    %// Preallocate to remove warnings
    ROLLING_WINDOWS = repmat(struct(), limit_rows, 1);

    for i = 1:limit_rows
        offset = bandwidth + i - 1;
        for j = 1:columns
            %// Dynamic field name referencing
            ROLLING_WINDOWS(i).(COMPANIES{j}) = RETURNS(i:offset, j);
        end
    end

end
```

Here's a great article by Loren Shure from MathWorks if you want to learn more: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/ ... but basically, if you have a string and you want to use this string to create a field, you would do:

```
str = '...';
s.(str) = ...;
```

`s` is your structure and `str` is the string you want to name your field.

Comment: Thanks mate! I just edited my question with a working function! How can I preallocate the ROLLING_WINDOWS variable?

Comment: @Zarathos np. Try now boss.